# PHP File includes app.php > App includes template.php > Template includes header.php & footer.php

Tags: php, file, templates, nested, include

This is our folder structure:

```
index.php
-app/
--app.php
---template/
----template.php
----parts/
-----head.php
-----header.php
-----body.php
-----(etc)
```

I am just basically using include in each file to import my html template.

index.php :

```
<?php 
include ('app/app.php');
?>
```

app.php :

```
<?php
include ('template/template.php');
?>
```

template/template.php :

```
<?php 

// Load our Head
include ('parts/head.php');

// Load our Header
include ('parts/header.php');

// Load our Body
include ('parts/body.php');

// Load our Footer
include ('parts/footer.php');

?>
```

Each head.php, body.php, etc... has an `<?php echo "test head" ?>` but in the end my result is a blank white page.

Comment: Do you have error output enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 reasons that this isn't working is because when you are including the other PHP files using "/" will reference the "/" of the index.php therefore in all the includes you must change "/" to __DIR__

as well as this in index.php using `include ('/app/app.php');` will fail to find the correct current directory and therefore for your specific case change the code to this:

index.php :

```
<?php 
include ('.\app\app.php');
?>
```

app.php :

```
<?php
include(__DIR__.'\template\template.php');
?>
```

template\template.php :

```
<?php

// Load our Head
include (__DIR__.'\parts\head.php');

// Load our Header
include (__DIR__.'\parts\header.php');

// Load our Body
include (__DIR__.'\parts\body.php');

// Load our Footer
include (__DIR__.'\parts\footer.php');

?>
```